# How to add a Glyphicon to NavDropdown in ReactBootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a glyphicon to a `NavDropdown` in React Bootstrap.
I know that you can add it to a normal `Dropdown` like this, as explained in the documentation.

```
<Dropdown id="dropdown-custom-1">
  <Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Glyphicon glyph="star" />
    Pow! Zoom!
  </Dropdown.Toggle>
  <Dropdown.Menu >
    <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

**What I've tried:**

**1. Does not work:**

```
    <NavDropdown eventKey={3} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
       <NavDropdown.Toggle>
       <Glyphicon glyph="star" />
       Pow! Zoom!
       </NavDropdown.Toggle>
       <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
    </NavDropdown>
```

**2. Does not work:**

```
    <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title={<Glyphicon glyph="star" /> Dropdown} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
       <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
    </NavDropdown>
```

**3. Does work but the caret is not aligned with the text and it appears in a new line:**

```
    <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title={<div><Glyphicon glyph="star" /> Dropdown </div>} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
       <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
    </NavDropdown>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try to pass a title through the `<Glyphicon />` component like this:

```
 render() {
     const navDropdownTitle = (<Glyphicon glyph="star"> Dropdown </Glyphicon>);
     return (
       <NavDropdown title={navDropdownTitle} eventKey={3} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
          <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
       </NavDropdown>
      )
}
```

(Update) Or we can use your approach but with small fix for div style. The font style does not break down in this case.

```
 <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title={<div style={{display: "inline-block"}}><Glyphicon glyph="star" /> Dropdown </div>} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
   <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
</NavDropdown>
```

And you probably will need to disable `text-decoration: underline` style to make drop-down look better.
For example with this css-rule:

```
a.dropdown-toggle {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This renders de title and the icon in line with the caret but the font for the title is wrong

Comment: Thanks, the `text-decoration` is not necessary, I didn't have to use it.
Also the `pull-left` class on the `div` also works.

Comment: The fix to this displaying problem to use a span around it.
`const navDropdownTitle = (<span><Glyphicon glyph="star" /> Dropdown </span>);`

Comment: for recent react version Glyphicon has been dropped, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons & https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons

Comment: Using `react-icons` package, and here's my title value: `const navAboutDropdownTitle = <span><FcInfo /> About</span>`. Thanks so much for this answer, saved me a ton of time / trying to do complex CSS changes...

Answer (score 0):

```
<NavDropdown title={<BsPersonCircle />} id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
   ...
</NavDropdown>
```